# passing array list to python argument

Tags: python, boto3

trying to pass an array list of ec2 instance ids to my python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3
import sys
import argparse
instance_id = list(sys.argv[1])
#aws_region = sys.argv[2]
tagname = sys.argv[2]
tagvalue = sys.argv[3]

EC2_RESOURCE = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-1')

def tag_instance(instance_id,tagname,tagvalue):
    
    TAGS = [
    {
        'Key': tagname,
        'Value': tagvalue
    }
    ]

    instances = EC2_RESOURCE.instances.filter(
    InstanceIds=[
        instance_id,
    ],
    )

    for instance in instances:
        instance.create_tags(Tags=TAGS)
    print(f'Tags successfully added to the instance {instance.id}')

tag_instance(instance_id,tagname,tagvalue)
```

but keep getting this error

```
Invalid type for parameter InstanceIds[0], 
value: ['i', '-', '0', '9', '2', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 
        'f', '1', 'e', '8', '2', 'f', '5', 'a', '1', ','], 
type: <class 'list'>, 
valid types: <class 'str'>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Please add how you are calling your program. I think there lies the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, the comma at the end of the instance name strikes me. I assume, you make some incorrect assumptions on how the command line is parsed.

Try the following. Change the following lines in your script:

```
instance_ids = sys.argv[1].split(",")
```

and

```
instances = EC2_RESOURCE.instances.filter(InstanceIds=instance_ids)
```

Then call the script as:

```
scriptname "instance1,instance2,instance3" tagname tagvalue
```

Alternatively, you can move tagname and tagvalue to position 1 and 2 and use position 3.. for the instance names:

```
tagname = sys.argv[1]
tagvalue = sys.argv[2]
instance_ids = sys.argv[3:]
```

Then call it:

```
scriptname tagname tagvalue instance1 instance2 instance3
```

A different point: Your print statement is indented incorrectly, it will only be executed after the loop. Correct your code as follows:

```
    for instance in instances:
        instance.create_tags(Tags=TAGS)
        print(f'Tags successfully added to the instance {instance.id}')
```

Comment: yes this works. what went wrong ? the output is only showing once instance though

Comment: Indent the print statement to put it inside the loop.

Comment: I want to pass my list of instances like so.   inst1 inst2  new line for each instance. is that posibble

Comment: Command lines are typically single lines. Check how to read user input or how to read from a file in python. Every beginner tutorial should cover those.